# Scroll vertically while keeping horizontal position

Tags: scrolling, column

I'm viewing a file containing visually aligned columns in truncate line mode, and would like to scroll vertically without changing my horizontal scroll position. But scroll-down always moves the cursor to the first column. Is there a simple way to prevent this, and keep the current horizontal point position?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for something like:

```
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position 'always)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will still scroll if e.g. point lands on an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Option `goal-column` might help in this regard. `C-h v goal-column` says:

> `goal-column` is a variable defined in `simple.el`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Semipermanent goal column for vertical motion, as set by `C-x C-n`, or `nil`.
>
> A non-`nil` setting overrides the variable `line-move-visual`, which see.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Thanks. It does the job, though it's behavior seems unintuitive as it is respected by C-n and C-p but not by C-v and M-v.